# Add field from RDD to other RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm using Pyspark and have to use RDDs (not dataframes) to do the following:

I have two RDDs, rdd1, containing more than 100 fields with names and rdd2, containing one field called "city". rdd1 and rdd2 have the same number of rows (same length).

rdd1 is like:

```
Row(name="Jack", age=35, state="California", ...)  
Row(name"Jane", age=29, state="Florida", ...)  
...
```

rdd2 is like:

```
Row(city="LA")  
Row(city="Miami")  
...
```

I would like rdd1 to become:

```
Row(name="Jack", age=35, state="California", ..., city="LA")  
...
```

Everything I've tried just failed. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `zip` method available for rdds.

```
rdd_zip = rdd1.zip(rdd2) 

#Flatten the rdd
rdd_final = rdd_zip.map(lambda x: tuple(list(x[0]) + [x[1]]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the first line zips the rdd, but the second line is not working!

Comment: @JackHoe What is the error you are getting with the last line?

Comment: The last line seems to work but then when I call rdd_final.take(3) to have a look, it just throws this error: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 26.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 26.0 (TID 45, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\opt\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\wo ...
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @JackHoe Try `rdd_zip.map(lambda x: [elem for elem in x])`. If it doesn't work can, print some lines of `rdd_zip` to check?

Comment: Now it works but the result is not exactly what I'm looking for  
RDD_ZIP IS LIKE : [(Row(name="Jack", age=35, ...), "LA"), (Row....)]   ###########                                       
RDD_FINAL IS LIKE : [[Row(name="Jack",age=35,..), "LA"], [Row...]] ###########                         
I'D LIKE [(Row(name="Jack,age=35,city="LA"), (Row...)]

Comment: @JackHoe Added a slight change to the answer `list(y)` instead of simply `y`. It should work for you.